# Migrate Dynamo Document.Item to aws-sdk-java-v2

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-java-2.0

Does anyone know where "com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.Item", item.fromJSON(), and Item.toJSON() are in the aws-sdk-java-v2?

I'm looking to migrate the following code:

-- From v1 --

```
AmazonDynamoDB dynamoDB = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder
...
DynamoDB dynamo = new DynamoDB(dynamoDB);
dbtable = dynamo.getTable(table);

dbtable.putItem(Item.fromJSON(jsonString));

Item item = dbtable.getItem(spec);
String jsonString = item.toJSON();
```

-- To v2 --

```
DynamoDbClient ddbClient = DynamoDbClient
.builder()
...
.build();

??? dbtable.putItem(Item.fromJSON(jsonString))
??? jsonString = dbtable.getItem(spec).toJSON()
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I fully understand you question, but if you are just looking for the code, it is here:

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/document/Item.java

starting at line 1236.

Comment: Your answer is for AWS SDK Java V1. See https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/aws-sdk-for-java-2-x-released/

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. The DynamoDB Document API **HAS NOT** been implemented in the aws-sdk-java-v2 libraries.

Github feature request can be found here: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/36